# GCP Service Account Permissions Query

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, authorization, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm getting started with GCP, and I've experience with AWS, so the IAM permissions and service accounts aren't new to me, but GCP is.

So I'm trying to introduce terraform to the company, and at present for simplicity, I created a service account, gave it a custom role, and of course it's getting authorization failures because apparently I'm missing something for network creation. Rather than try to narrow my search down for "which permissions I need" is there a way in the Logs Explorer to find "your service account X tried to do Y actions, result: Z"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are looking for a way to see the activity of the service account.[Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit) is a good option to see this and you have several ways to [view Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#viewing_audit_logs) logs, including [Log Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface).

Documentation on [Audit logs for service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging/examples-service-accounts) might be helpful.[Advanced logs queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) to precise the search from the logs.For more details on [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts), and the IAM roles that are available to service accounts. Just for reference, Policy Troubleshooter is helpful to [Troubleshooting access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access) as it examines all IAM policies that apply to the resource.

Comment: Yeah, I had originally found that when searching and browsing through, but just ran into difficulty because it didn't seem like I could do a blanket search on the service account. Which, is fine, if I have to do the four searches between audit, resource, data, etc., that's fine. Just didn't know if anyone had a better or simpler way. Thanks!